# Docker Status Running, but unable to do docker ps

Tags: azure, docker, azure-dsvm

I'm trying to setup model management service on Azure Data Science VM by following the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/desktop-workbench/deployment-setup-configuration. I have added myself as a root user added the same into the docker usergroup, However i cant get docker running. Attached the screenshot fore reference. Can someone help.

[image: Docker Status]

Comment: What error are you getting, when you run docker ps command? Try to change permission for docker.sock file 'sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock' and then try again.

Comment: Looks like this is related to the permission, i redeployed the same instance and it seems to work now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Rohan,

Definitely looks to be a permissions issue.

Similar issues in the past for me have been permissions related. something like the below usually works as Rohan advised:
`sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock`

Glad to hear its working now

Comment: Did you find a fix for this Ilyas?